# Perform data manipulation for each year found

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I have a dataframe which lists country relations and years associated. I have created a set of operations that I wish to perform for each year but currently am doing that 1 year at a time individually.

Is there a way to create sort of a loop or iteration that will start at the lowest year, perform all the operations, then increment up to the next year and repeat itself to the end?

Below is an example of what my DF looks like, I wish to perform calculations on all rows labeled with 2017, write out to a .csv (named with the year), and then repeat the process for all rows labeled with 2018.

So with the end result I would hopefully have multiple .csvs labeled something like Output2017.csv, Output2018.csv, etc

[image]

Comment: Why not get a list of unique years and loop over them to do your operations. We can be of more help if you can input

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, I am working with the years 1990-2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, let's say you have a function `foo(df)` that takes a dataframe, `df`, and processes it to produce your desired output.

Then you can do

```
list_of_dfs_by_year <- split(data, data$Year)
```

To create a named list of dataframes, grouped by year. Then you can call

```
lapply(list_of_dfs_by_year, foo)
```

Comment: with this solution, how would I create individually named csvs by each year?

Comment: Let `processed_dfs <- lapply(list_of_dfs_by_year, foo)` and `filenames <- paste0(names(processed_dfs), ".csv"))`. Then do `Map(write.csv, processed_dfs, filenames)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with **dplyr**:

```
> df <- tibble(country = letters[1:11], year = 2000:2010)
> seqns <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% arrange(year) %>% select(year)
> seqns <- seqns$year
> for (y in seqns) {
+     print(df %>% filter(year == y))
+ }
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  country  year
  <chr>   <int>
1 a        2000
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  country  year
  <chr>   <int>
1 b        2001
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  country  year
  <chr>   <int>
1 c        2002
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  country  year
  <chr>   <int>
1 d        2003
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  country  year
  <chr>   <int>
1 e        2004
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  country  year
  <chr>   <int>
1 f        2005
```

...

and then take the corresponding actions to save in csv.

See more details [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html).